# Add parameter to breadcrumb rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, breadcrumbs

I am using the [breadcrumbs on rails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails) gem. And I would like to know how to pass a parameter to a path. Something like this:

add_breadcrumb "Home", :my_path @my_parameter

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easiest to set up the the path in your *routes.rb* accepting a parameter, then you don't need to worry about passing it